# Objective-C Library for RSS feed parsing?

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, rss, ios

I'm looking for an Objective-C library for an iOS app that will parse and display articles form an RSS feed.

Specifically,m I'm looking to make an app for a news website. The framework should be able to work with various RSS XML structures if possible. (Well, two different news sites. One uses Wordpress-generated RSS and one does not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Apples [NSXMLParser Class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSXMLParser). Or you could use the C-based [libXML2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).

Answer (score 7):

[MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) is another interesting library to look into.

Answer (score 5):

How about https://github.com/touchcode/TouchRSS?

Answer (score 4):

My drop-in solution (deals with Wordpress' RSS 2.0 and the Atom 1.0 format as well): http://github.com/H2CO3/RSSKit

Answer (score 0):

This library is about as old as this question: https://github.com/NextfazeSD/WordPressSyncer. It syncs WordPress blogs from the server, saving data locally in a core data database.