# How to fetch the data from Google news by XML Parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to fetch Google news data by XML parsing and save it into an array. The XML is like this

http://news.google.co.in/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&output=rss

Comment: check these thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488409/objective-c-library-for-rss-feed-parsing

Comment: Did you try to search for an XML parsing?? Show some effort. Everyone will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I parse xml some different way than others and being frank I really do not know which technique it is but I assure you it works fine for me and I have implemeted it successfully in so many projects. Have a look at my code where I load tweets from some [profile](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=SrBachchan&count=5)

> **This is the function where I make call for parser.**

```
-(void)loadtweet
{
@try
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=SrBachchan&count=5"];

    NSLog(@"fetching data from--------> : %@",urlString);

    NSString* escapedUrlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString]];

    NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc]  initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];
    if(con)
        truckData=[[NSMutableData data]retain];
}

@catch (NSException *exception) 
{
    UIAlertView *v = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"Please Try Again Later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [v show];
    [v release];
}

}
```

> **And these are the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods:**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
[truckData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
[truckData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 

{
   [tweets removeAllObjects];
 @try 
{
    // [app.trucks removeAllObjects];
    NSString *thexml=[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[truckData mutableBytes] length:[truckData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *array=[thexml componentsSeparatedByString:@"<status>"];
    NSLog(@"%d",[array count]);

    for(int i=1;i<[array count];i++)
    {
        NSString *str=[array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *arr1=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"<text>"];
        NSString *data=[arr1 objectAtIndex:1];
        NSRange ranfrom=[data rangeOfString:@"</text>"];
        // nt.truckName=[data substringToIndex:ranfrom.location];
        [tweets  addObject:[data substringToIndex:ranfrom.location]];
    }
}

@catch (NSException *exception) 
{
    UIAlertView *v = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"Please Try Again Later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [v show];
    [v release];
 }

}
```

I have used some string functions to separate tags and stored the values in Array.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you can start: [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.